# Can I use mockito for partial overriding of existing objects (not just for testing)?

Tags: java, mockito, aop

I have a following issue. I have a method that uses an implementation of Connection. That is, the method looks like this:

```
try (Connection conn = getConnection()) {
  // Do some queries here
}
```

However, we need to have an exact statistic, how many queries did this method execute, and there are a lot of such methods, that we need to analyze. So here is what I came up with

```
try (Connection conn = new LogCountConnection(getConnection)) {
  // Do some queries here
}
```

The LogCountConnection basically passes all it's calls to the standard implementation, but for some methods it increments the counter value, and the close method is overridden like this:

```
@Override
public void close() throws SQLException {
  log.info(String.format("Number of queries executed: %d", counter));
  conn.close();
}
```

However, it looks really tedious, that I have to actually create a whole new class there methods look mostly like this:

```
@Override
public boolean getAutoCommit() throws SQLException {
 return conn.getAutoCommit();
}
```

This definitely looks like something from AOP, but we are not using in our project AspectJ or something like that. Can I use mockito for partial mocking of methods on existing object for that, or is too risky and should be used only strictly in tests?

Comment: do you understand what mocking does? it basically creates a dummy, not actual functioning code. it seems to me that you are somewhat looking for a static method./factory

Comment: Not quite, you can make a mock on a real object, with spy() help.

Comment: Not sure why you think of a custom class for this as "tedious". This is basically just classical delegation...

Comment: I agree, this is classical delegation, however Connection interface has several dozens of methods, and to create a whole class for that looks really a tedious job, although I did that. I am just curious if there is a more elegant method to do that in Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in comments, mocking or spying most likely won't solve your problem.

The classical delegation can probably avoided in your use case by implementing dynamic proxies. Intercepting just some methods of `Connection` interface becomes possible with according branching in `InvocationHandler`. The article https://jaxenter.de/jdbc-treiber-selbstgebaut-java-trickkiste-636 (unfortunately in German only) outlines a solution to a similar problem as yours.

Comment: Thanks,  the code is quite clear, now I know what to do.

Comment: If you want to avoid the performance overhead of dynamic proxies and their inability to work on internal method calls (method in class A calls another method in the same class), you can use AspectJ for this cross-cutting concern. The beauty of AOP is that you can even deactivate the aspect if you do not need it, your core code is absolutely unaware of it if done right.